# Enviar array para o Controller e inserir na DB, com Ajax e Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, array, codeigniter

Olá,

Não estou a conseguir receber (no controller) o array que é enviado de uma View através de ajax. 
Já testei no console.log e o array é enviado mas no controller nada acontece.

o input, "numdias" define o numero de inputs com a data a ser inserido (o array a ser enviado para o controller).

Segue o código correspondente:

View:

```
 <div class="form-group">                               
                                <label>Numero de dias a adicionar:</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="numDiasAnuais" id="txtNumDias" min="0"/>

                            </div>
                            <div id="divForm"></div>
                            <template id="tmplLinha">
                                <div class="form-group">                                    
                                <input type="text" name="data[]" id="data" readonly="readonly" class="inserir_data form-control datasIndisponiveis"/>                                
                            </div>
                            </template>                                
                             <div class="form-group">                 
                                <button type="submit" name="submitAddDatasAnuaisIndisponiveis" id="submitAddDatasAnuaisIndisponiveis" class="form-control">Adicionar</button> 
                                <button type="button" class="form-control " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaldataindisponiveis">Listar Datas</button>                                    
                            </div>
```

Ajax:

```
//dATAS INDISPONIVEIS
$("#submitAddDatasAnuaisIndisponiveis").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();



    var dataIndisponivel = new Array();        

    $("input.datasIndisponiveis").each(function(){
        dataIndisponivel.push($(this).val());

    })  

    console.log(dataIndisponivel);     


    jQuery.ajax({      

    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('sistema/addDatasIndisponiveis'); ?>",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {dataIndisponivel},
    success: function(res) {
    if (res)
    {
      $('#mensagensErro').html(res);
      $("#error-dialog").modal("show");          
      //$("input#data").val('');


    }
    }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
// #40
public function addDatasIndisponiveis()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == true && $this->session->userdata('nivel') == 0) {
        // $this->load->library('form_validation');
        // $this->form_validation->set_rules('data[]', 'Datas', 'required|is_unique[tbldataindisponivel.data]');
        // if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

        //     $res = '<div style="color:red;">'.validation_errors().'</div>';
        //     echo json_encode('$res');
        //     exit;


        // } else {
            $datas = $this->input->post('data[]');
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($datas); $i++) {
                $inserir = $this->sistema_model->addDatasIndisponiveis($datas[$i]);
            }
            if ($inserir) {
                $res = '<div style="color:green;">Adicionado com sucesso</div>';
            }else{
                $res = '<div style="color:red;">Erro</div>';
            }

            echo json_encode($res);
            exit;
       // }

    } else {

        redirect('inicio/index', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Comment: Não podes usar assim `data: {dataIndisponivel},` uma vez que `dataIndisponivel` é uma array. Testa `data: {datas: dataIndisponivel},` e depois `$datas = $this->input->post('datas');`. Funciona?

Comment: Sergio, obrigado funcionou, :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No ajax tens `data: {dataIndisponivel},` que é sitaxe inválida.

Um objeto tem de ter uma chave e um valor `{chave: valor}` e neste caso falta-te a chave.

Assim podes mudar para `data: {datas: dataIndisponivel},` no JavaScript e mudar no controlador para `$datas = $this->input->post('datas');`.

Assim passas a mesma chave no ajax como a que estás a selecionar no controlador.